# filtering rows in pandas: where vs. binary filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to keep the rows where s1_held and s2_held are 0

when I do this:

```
p = events[(events['s1_held'] == 0.0) & (events['s2_held'] == 0.0)]
```

it works properly and I get that:

[image]

but if I do this:

```
p = events.where((events['s1_held'] == 0.0) & (events['s2_held'] == 0.0))
```

then I get that:

[image]

Can someone explain me why where keeps the index with no data?

Comment: Where is not for filtering. It returns the rows where the condition is met with the original data, all the others will be returned as `NaN`

Comment: If you want another method for filtering, use: `events.query('s1_held == 0) & (s2_held == 0')` which is more concise

Comment: Read this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html